# Why openpyxl reads some empty/blank excels cells as <ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.D2>?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a simple code where I am reading an excel .xlsx file as a dataframe and then writing it back as a pickle file using *to_pickle*. I have been using the same code for months to read and write as new excel files arrive. However, this time when I tried my code it is giving me **TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object** error for some reason. Here is the code,

```
# Path to .xlsx
MasterItem = MonthlyFolder + "MasterItem__Nov2019.xlsx"

# Function to read the excel file
def ReadExcel(filename, sheetname=None, header=0):
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb = load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)

    if sheetname is None:  # If sheetname is not provided then grab the first sheet
        print("\t Reading " + wb.sheetnames[0])
        ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
    else:
        print("\t Reading " + sheetname)
        ws = wb[sheetname]

    data = ws.values

    if header is None:
        columns = None
    elif header > 0:
        # Skip non header rows
        for i in range(0, header):
            next(data)
        # Save header row
        columns = next(data)[0:]
    else:
        columns = next(data)[0:]

    # Create a DataFrame based on the subsequent lines of data
    df_Out = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

    return df_Out

# Reading .xlsx and writing as pickle
RawMasterItem = ReadExcel(MasterItem)
pd.to_pickle(RawMasterItem, MonthlyFolder+"RawMasterItem.pkl") # This fails to run
```

Following is the output and error I am getting,

```
    ../Data/2019Nov/MasterItem__Nov2019.xlsx
         Reading Sheet1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Eulhaq\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-10-07041bb51f98>", line 3, in <module>
        pd.to_pickle(RawMasterItem, MonthlyFolder+"RawMasterItem.pkl")
      File "C:\Users\Eulhaq\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 76, in to_pickle
        f.write(pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=protocol))
    TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

After debugging I have realized that openpyxl is reading and returning some blank cells as **`<ReadOnlyCell 'Sheet1'.D2`>**. Don't know why is it happening. I have checked the excel file and there are no hidden characters at these locations. Any idea why openpyxl is unable to read some cells as blanks like it is able to do for others?

Comment: Have you tried: ```RawMasterItem.to_pickle(MonthlyFolder+"RawMasterItem.pkl")```

Comment: It turns out, some blank cells in my data are empty while these problematic blank cells have **new line** characters in them. It appears to me that **openpyxl** is unable to properly read a cell with just **new line** character in it.